# custom CSS file

Tags: css, custom

I created a custom CSS file and I linked the file using "Master Page Setting" alternate CSS URL option to the SharePoint 2013 site. It works fine in my computer but it doesn't work from an user's computer. I am not sure why. Any suggestions? I am using seattle.html as a master file.Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Minimal Download Strategy feature on your sites?

Comment: Where are you hosting the CSS file?  Is it in a document library that requires check-in and publishing before files are available to all?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check multiple things as issue is not clear:

1. First see if your css is checked in and published.If not users will not see this.
2. Please look into css if you are finding any issues.
3. Also try to add the CSS to the master page using CSS registration tag and publish it.

> ```
> <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/_catalogs/masterpage/truesec/truesec.css" runat="server"/>
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. The css file was not published. After I published all users can see the changes.

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer so that it could be helpful to everyone

Comment: After the custom css file is uploaded to the SharePoint it's needed to be publish. If it is not publish, the changes won't be seen from users' computers